# Have "Interactable" been removed from Unity as a scripting API?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sorry for the basic question, but I'm following a tutorial on YouTube to create a combat system in Unity and there is code in the Enemy class that indicates that the class uses Ineractable

```
public class Enemy : Interactable
```

But I'm getting an error that says

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Interactable' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Interactable must be a class that's created in the tutorial. Check if you've missed a step or something. If you could link the tutorial your following that would help.

Comment: @leoQuint that might be it, i just looked up the one part i needed and that video was episode 11 of a series so I'll have to look back through the other videos to find it. Thanks!

Comment: https://youtu.be/9tePzyL6dgc probably this is from here